# Typescript variável dentro de função aloca informação fora dele ela é vazia

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar uma variável dentro dessa função

```
    this.rooms.subscribe(
  function (x) {
      y= x[0].id;
      alert(y)
    });
```

mas quando acesso ela fora da função ela volta ao valor dela inicial

aqui o código todo:

```
openChat(cid, nome) {
    let y = ''

    this.rooms = this.db.collection<roomMembers>
      ('room-members', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', this.uid).where('uidOutro', '==', cid)).valueChanges();

    this.rooms.subscribe(
      function (x) {
        y = x[0].id;
        alert(y)
      }
    );
    alert(y)

    this.navCtrl.push(Chat, {
      uid: cid,
      nome: nome,
      id: y
    });

  }
```

Comment: E isto? `this.db.collection<roomMembers>`? Isso não é JS. Seria typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que essa função `subscribe` é assíncrona. Isso quer dizer que o seu `alert` de fora executa *antes* de você alterar o valor de `y`. Você só pode usar `y` depois de ter atribuído um valor dentro do callback. Ou seja, faça assim:

```
openChat(cid, nome) {
    let y = ''

    this.rooms = this.db.collection<roomMembers> // isso é typescript?
      ('room-members', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', this.uid).where('uidOutro', '==', cid)).valueChanges();

    let contexto = this;
    this.rooms.subscribe(
      function (x) {
        y = x[0].id;
        contexto.navCtrl.push(Chat, {
          uid: cid,
          nome: nome,
          id: y
        });
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando voce usa LET está limitando o valor dela ao escopo onde foi declarado.

Quando voce reutiliza a variavel **y = x[0].id;**, colocou esse novo valor de y em um novo escopo.

Para resolver seu problema use VAR no lugar de LET, ou refatore o codigo, de modo que o valor seja retornado.

Comment: Além do problema de escopo, tem cara de que essa função é assíncrona. Se for isso mesmo, simplesmente usar `var` não irá resolver.

Comment: ai melhor refatorar

Comment: Aliás, relendo o código, não tem problema de escopo. Ele está acessando sempre dentro do escopo.

Comment: ele ta fazendo uma operacao dentro de uma funcao. Ali o js ta jogando um novo escopo

Comment: Não, porque a declaração foi feita fora, a função acessa a variável de fora. Mas tem mais coisa estranha nesse código, principalmente a parte com sintaxe de Generics, que não existe em javascript